# Deleted my Wired Connection and now my Ethernet Controller has no logical name, and my ethernet port is dead

Tags: networking, ethernet

I was trying to set up a wired connection in Kubuntu 23.04 and nothing was connecting.

I right clicked Wired Connection 1 in Connections and clicked Delete, then rebooted, and noticed that my Ethernet port was now completely dead.

I looked up my network devices on lshw and found that my Ethernet Controller no longer has a logical name (literally there isn't even a "logical name" line), and under configuration it only shows latency=0.

Any way to fix this seems to be referring to /etc/network/interfaces which I no longer have (because of the newer version), and NetPlan has not been helpful, my YAML file is nearly empty.

Comment: This might be of assistance to re-establish your connection and re-create a wired connection. https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wired.html.en Are you on a second machine to ask the forum?